# Permanently activate WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development, admin

It it possible to permanently activate a theme so that it cannot be disabled or changed?

Something similar to:

```
define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'apollo' );
```

Comment: the context is not very clear, even if it is possible anyone with FTP access will be able to change it.

Comment: Have you tried removing all the other themes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one idea:

```
/**
 * Reactivate the sticky theme, if someone activates another theme.
 */

add_action( 'switch_theme', 'wpse_permanent_theme' );

function wpse_permanent_theme( $new_name )
{
    $sticky_theme_name = 'twentyfifteen';  // Modify this to your needs!

    // Get the sticky theme info, to check if it exists (named):    
    $sticky_theme = wp_get_theme( $sticky_theme_name );

    // Reactivate the sticky theme:   
    if( $sticky_theme->get( 'Name' ) && $sticky_theme_name !== $new_name )
    {
        remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );
        switch_theme( $sticky_theme_name );
    }
}
```

where you have to modify the sticky theme name to your needs. You may need to test this further.

Another thing to try out would be to remove the `switch_themes` *capability* for all users!

For example, we can filter out this capability on the fly with:

```
/**
 *  Remove the 'switch_themes' capability for all users.
 */

add_filter('user_has_cap', function( $allcaps )
{
    if( isset( $allcaps['switch_themes']  ) )
        unset( $allcaps['switch_themes'] );
    return $allcaps;
});
```

so the `current_user_can( 'switch_themes' )` check during a theme activation in `themes.php` returns false.

Comment: thanks @SörenWrede for the edit, I'm playing with the twentyfifteen and the twentyeleven themes, as you can see ;-)